# extjs - fit font text inside button properly on smaller button

Tags: css, button, extjs

In my extjs project I have a menu button inside the header of a grid.  I am trying to make the font fit inside the small area of button.  It looks like the bigger I make the text the more it moves down.  How can I make it fit inside the button properly?

here is the view

```
                xtype: 'grid',
            itemId: 'detailsGridID',
            bind: {
                store: '{myDetailsStore}'
            },
            header: {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Trades',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 15,
                    cls: 'buttonTopdayCSS',
                    menu: [{
                        text: 'Net',
                        handler: function () {
                            alert('click net');
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Topday',
                        handler: function () {
                            alert('click topday');
                        }
                    }]
                }]
```

here is the css class

```
.buttonTopdayCSS {
background-color: #a7cfdf; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#a7cfdf), to(#23538a));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a7cfdf, #23538a);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a7cfdf, #23538a);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a7cfdf, #23538a);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a7cfdf, #23538a);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a7cfdf, #23538a);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#a7cfdf, endColorstr=#23538a);
}

.buttonTopdayCSS .x-btn-inner {
font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try adding `padding: 0; border: 0;` to `.buttonTopdayCSS`.

Comment: thank you... this worked!!  adding padding and border in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons have a [scale configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-scale). I would try this. I would stick to override styles as few as possible.

```
 scale: 'large'
```

If this special style is a requirement throughout your app and not only at this place, look into [theming](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html).

Comment: thank you, I tried scale small and it was still a bit too large.  Out of curiosity, why should I have few override styles?  Does it slow things down?

Comment: I did not mean not to override some styles. I mean that if you want change the theme, you can use the integrated theming engine. If it is just about one button, this will not be worth the hassle. Extjs theming is powerful, but it is difficult to achieve what you want.